# Get highest and lowest in every element from multiple arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have this array with 4 arrays of 18 elements (** refers to result, not part of code/array):

```
highlow: [["-5", "8", "-8", "13", "17", "11", "17", "4", "17", "18", "18", "10", "-8", "-13", "-22", "-16", "-3", "27"],
["5", "**15**", "6", "-11", "-18", "-7", "-6", "7", "-10", "5", "6", "-6", "-12", "-10", "-7", "14", "10", "23"],
["-6", "7", "8", "18", "6", "14", "24", "14", "6", "13", "8", "18", "-14", "-15", "-9", "-13", "14", "12"],
["-19", "-12", "14", "20", "15", "20", "11", "19", "13", "5", "2", "-14", "5", "6", "16", "-5", "8", "30"]]
```

I need to get two new arrays with the highest of the 18 elements, and one with the lowest. 
I have made this:

```
var highlow = [];
var high = [];
var low = [];

for (i = 0; i < 18; i++) { 
        high.push("0");
        low.push("0");
}                   

 for (var l = 0; l < highlow.length; l++) {

                   for (var m = 0; m < highlow[0].length; m++) {
                      // High   
                          if (highlow[l][m] > high[m]) {
                              high.splice(m, 1, highlow[l][m]);
                          }    
                      // Low
                          if (highlow[l][m] < low[m]) {
                              low.splice(m, 1, highlow[l][m]);  
                          } 
                     }
                   }
```

But the result i get is this, on the second high element it return 8, but that should be 15 (see **):

```
high:
 ["5","**8**","8","20","6","20","24","7","6","5","8","18","5","6","16","14","8","30"]
low:
 ["-19","-12","14","-11","15","-7","11","19","13","5","2","-14","-14","-15","-9","-5","-3","12"]
```

I cant figure out how to manage this...

Underscore.js is tagged, if that could be a shortcut...

Comment: It does not look clear to me.
You have an array of array called "highlow" and you want to process it into two arrays. One with the 18 lower elements of "highlow" named "low" and one with the 18 higher named "high" right? 
From what I see, it's not only that 8 the problem. Can you print an example with the expected results?

Comment: So do you think `'24'` is higher than `'8'`?

Comment: Ok yes it was an example (sorry not being totally clear), to show the first wrong element, but yes thers many errors ;)

Comment: There's mainly 1 error, all your numbers have `"'s` surrounding them, remove all the `"` it might work.  Did you know there are 10 type's of people who understand binary, those that do, and those that don't..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting those results because you're comparing strings, not numbers.

```js
console.log("15" > "8"); // false
console.log(15 > 8); // true
```

Converting to numbers when doing the comparison give the correct results:

```js
var input =  [
    ["-5",  "8",   "-8", "13",  "17",  "11", "17", "4",  "17",  "18", "18", "10",  "-8",  "-13", "-22", "-16", "-3", "27"],
    ["5",   "15",  "6",  "-11", "-18", "-7", "-6", "7",  "-10", "5",  "6",  "-6",  "-12", "-10", "-7",  "14",  "10", "23"],
    ["-6",  "7",   "8",  "18",  "6",   "14", "24", "14", "6",   "13", "8",  "18",  "-14", "-15", "-9",  "-13", "14", "12"],
    ["-19", "-12", "14", "20",  "15",  "20", "11", "19", "13",  "5",  "2",  "-14", "5",   "6",   "16",  "-5",  "8",  "30"]
];

var high = [];
var low = [];
for (var i=0; i<input[0].length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j<input.length; j++) {
       if (!high[i] || Number(input[j][i]) > Number(high[i])) { high[i] = input[j][i];}
       if (!low[i]  || Number(input[j][i]) < Number(low[i]))  { low[i]  = input[j][i];}
    }
}

console.log("high:", high);
console.log("low:", low);
```

(I swapped the order in which the arrays are evaluated so you wouldn't have to preinitialize the output, but otherwise this is similar to your code except for the `Number()` conversions.)

Comment: Ahh i see, added parseInt() :) 
But the result on the low array have 0 not the lowest positive number.

Comment: @MartinLyder Whoops!  Silly mistake on my part, now corrected.

Comment: Yes!! It works, thank you!! I accept this answer :) It is the one that is closest to my own code...

Answer (score 1):

Use [Math.min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) and [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```
var high = [], low = [];
for (i = 0; i < highlow[0].length; i++) {
  var col = highlow.map(val => val[i]);
  high.push(col.reduce((a,b)=>Math.max(a,b)));
  low.push(col.reduce((a,b)=>Math.min(a,b)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drop all the values into a singular array, sort the values, and then cut the array in half to create your high and low value arrays.

```
let superArray = [];
superArray.push( highlow[0] );
superArray.push( highlow[1] );
superArray.push( highlow[2] );
superArray.push( highlow[3] );

superArray.sort();

let lowArray = superArray.splice(0, superArray.length -1);
let highArray = superArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the min and max values.

```js
function highlow(array) {
    return array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        if (!i) {
            r.low = a.slice();
            r.high = a.slice();
            return r;
        }
        a.forEach(function (b, j) {
            r.low[j] = Math.min(r.low[j], b);
            r.high[j] = Math.max(r.high[j], b);
        })
        return r;
    }, { low: [], high: [] });
}

console.log(highlow([["-5", "8", "-8", "13", "17", "11", "17", "4", "17", "18", "18", "10", "-8", "-13", "-22", "-16", "-3", "27"], ["5", "15", "6", "-11", "-18", "-7", "-6", "7", "-10", "5", "6", "-6", "-12", "-10", "-7", "14", "10", "23"], ["-6", "7", "8", "18", "6", "14", "24", "14", "6", "13", "8", "18", "-14", "-15", "-9", "-13", "14", "12"], ["-19", "-12", "14", "20", "15", "20", "11", "19", "13", "5", "2", "-14", "5", "6", "16", "-5", "8", "30"]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it help :

```
var highlow =[["-5", "8", "-8", "13", "17", "11", "17", "4", "17", 
    "18", "18", "10", "-8", "-13", "-22", "-16", "-3", "27"],
    ["5", "15", "6", "-11", "-18", "-7", "-6", "7", "-10", "5", "6", 
    "-6", 
    "-12", "-10", "-7", "14", "10", "23"],
    ["-6", "7", "8", "18", "6", "14", "24", "14", "6", "13", "8", 
    "18", 
    "-14", "-15", "-9", "-13", "14", "12"],
    ["-19", "-12", "14", "20", "15", "20", "11", "19", "13", "5", "2", 
    "-14", "5", "6", "16", "-5", "8", "30"]]

var high=[];
var low=[];
highlow.map((a)=>{
    hight.push(Math.max(...a));
    low.push(Math.min(...a));
});
```